# How do I run the following Python and Boto3 code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to explore machine learning models from AWS. AWS recently released a Bedrock service, and I would like to setup an environment to do that. I would also need to interact with S3, Langchain and Vector databases (e.g.Pinecone). There's a bit of an idea here on what i'd likely be playing with and i'd try to follow this: [EXAMPLE](https://github.com/generative-ai-on-aws/generative-ai-on-aws/blob/main/12_bedrock/01_bedrock_overview.ipynb)

I have VS Code on my PC, and i've seen a guide that details some of the steps to set this up with Pythin and Boto3: [GUIDE](https://hands-on.cloud/install-boto3-python/)

The thing i see from the Example link, is that i'm guessing Jupyter notbeook is used. Also (and please excuse my naievity), if i'm putting S3 files into a Vector database, these services would need to be spun up (or setup) ***surely***, and paid for by me. Otherwise where would this Vector database be located and where would Langchain run?

So for example running:

```
%pip install --no-build-isolation --force-reinstall \
    "boto3>=1.28.57" \
    "awscli>=1.29.57" \
    "botocore>=1.31.57"

%pip install --quiet langchain==0.0.309
```

How and where would you type this to run?

After that, the Vector database would just be queried via AWS Bedrock (which handles a lot of the underlying stuff). So i guess my other questions are for getting data into the Vector database initially:

Do i need AWS Sagemaker? I see in setting up SageMaker, that you can specify EC2 or some compute power.
Is there a simple way to work with this Example without SageMaker, or SageMaker is the easiest to setup and utilise?

Or is the guide linked here enough?

Essentially, to work with the Example i linked, what should my setup be?

Comment: _How and where would you type this to run?_ The documentation says "this notebook", so I assume it is run inside of a jupyter notebook.

Comment: This is quite new to me, so I understand there's Jupyter notebooks (wheredo the AWS services run?), SageMaker (which can have notebooks)...are there other setups i should be aware of? I mean SageMaker does lock you in a bit technologically as compared to VS Code + Python +some runtime space (which is more agnostic)